# MS Word Object Reference issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

what object reference do I need to make this function work .

```
Dim oDoc As Word.Application =
```

I have already selected  `Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library`

but i still get this error

[image]

this function simply finds and opens the Ms Word.exe then takes a file and adds it to the Ms Word file .

I'm sure that i'm missing an object reference but i don't not know which it is .

Comment: No missing reference. But it should be **Dim oDoc As Word.Document= ...** Instead of **Dim oDoc As Word.Application = ...**

Comment: @Chris: Please post as an answer. for AltCoder to accept it. It's always best to have an accepted answer that `[Resolved]` hints in the question topic or similar hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No missing reference. But you are trying to cast a `Word.Document` to `Word.Application` with `oDoc`, the cast is not valid.

It should be

```
Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Add()
```

Instead of

```
Dim oDoc As Word.Application = oWord.Documents.Add()
```